# How do I check if a firestore arrray contains a specified field?

Tags: arrays, typescript, firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I want to authenticate my users to the Admin UI if they have the reference called 'roles/admin' in their firestore user document.

I've tried many things like .find, .includes, etc. but couldn't get a functioning authenticator.

Here is my authenticator.tsx:

```
import {Authenticator} from "@camberi/firecms";
import {User as FirebaseUser} from "@firebase/auth";
import {userSchema} from "../schemas/user.schema";

export const authenticator: Authenticator<FirebaseUser> = async ({ user, dataSource}) => {
    if (!user?.uid) return false
    const entity = await dataSource.fetchEntity({
        path: `/users`,
        entityId: user.uid,
        schema: userSchema,
    })

    if (
        // Check if user has admin reference
    ) return true
    
    throw new Error(
        'ERROR: Only admins allowed. Please contact your developer!'
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {Authenticator} from "@camberi/firecms";
import {User as FirebaseUser} from "@firebase/auth";
import {userSchema} from "../schemas/user.schema";

export const authenticator: Authenticator<FirebaseUser> = async ({ user, dataSource}) => {
if (!user?.uid) return false
const entity = await dataSource.fetchEntity({
    path: `/users`,
    entityId: user.uid,
    schema: userSchema,
})

//add  that lines in your  code // start
const roles = entity?.data?.roles || []

if (roles.includes('admin')) {
    return true
}//end
else {
    throw new Error(
        'ERROR: Only admins allowed. Please contact your developer!'
    )
 }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks.

Comment: it's my pleasure